# How to save a picture after cropping in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, save, crop

I used Photoshop CS6 to crop a photo and I don't see any way to save the image.  Where is there a save button?

Comment: ...in the `File` menu?

Answer (score 2):

For PC the keyboard shortcut is:

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save as a new file (thus keeping the original file)

For Mac the keyboard shortcut is:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save as a new file (thus keeping the original file)

The other way you can save it is the `File` at the top of the screen. If the file menu is not showing up, you may be in fullscreen mode, in which case just press <kbd>F</kbd> until the menu at the top of the screen shows up again.

[image: File > Save]
[image: File > Save As]

*Although these images are from Adobe Creative Cloud the saving process is the same in CS6, CS5, CS4, and CS3 (probably all the way back, but for sure to CS3).*

If you `Save As...` you will need to rename your file something other than the original file, or save it in a new place on your computer.

Comment: It might not seem worth mentioning, since we're all more than a little bit familiar with Photoshop, but you have to commit the crop (press Enter or click the tick) before you get out of the crop tool and back to the image.

Comment: Good point @StanRogers I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score -1):

You can always hit <kbd>Control / Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control / Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ( to do `Save as...` )